# Newbie ASP.NET MVC 5 Model stored procedure heavy backend advice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got an enterprise app that relied heavily on stored procedures for business logic. I'm thinking about redoing the front end from Webforms to ASP.NET MVC but I'm hoping I don't have to write a model for each stored procedure (there are hundreds). Often times the "Get" stored procedures do not have the same parameters as the equivalent "set" stored procedures do and often times a single stored procedure is updating multiple database tables.

So my question is what is the best practice for building an ASP.NET MVC app on this kind of back end?  Will entity framework work for this?  I'm sure hoping I don't have to build 100's of models, one or two for each stored procedure...

I'm also looking into just using plain razor web pages with webdata's dynamic data row model it might be a better fit. But then I can't use neat things like Kendo UI so much (I think).

Thank you for your wisdom in advance.

Comment: So, from your question, sound like you are planning an architecture, but it's not clear what the app does, what is the current architecture and what are the requirements to the architecture or the tech stack. What are you hoping to achieve with this rewrite? What is the budget in terms of hours?

Comment: IMHO, ASP.Net is ASP.Net - depending on how you're currently doing data in WebForms, you can try (simply) thinking of `MVC` or `WebPages` as the "front end" (using whatever db calls/infrastructure currently exist in WebForms). But if you're also thinking of redoing the existing data infrastructure, then DonO's answer is they way to go (service layer, EF or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a model for every stored procedure.

It all depends on what you you want to do.

When i save data to the db using a stored proc I send in paramaters for each value I want to save.

When getting values from db I use a model. The model you use here is obviously up to you, if you are reciving file data then you can have a FileModel, imageData , ImageModel etc.

Example:

I use manager and service classes for this:

```
public void UpdateCustomerCredentials(long id, string firstName, string lastName, string email, string mobilePhoneNumber, int price, string notes, Guid? imageId = null)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateCustomer", con))
        {

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", id));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", firstName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", lastName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", email));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MobilePhoneNumber", mobilePhoneNumber));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageId", GetParamValue(imageId)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Price", price));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Notes", notes));

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteReader();

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the data using a customer model:

```
    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        List<Customer> customers;
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = null;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllCustomers", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    customers = (from x in sqlDataReader.Cast<DbDataRecord>()
                                 select new Customer
                                 {
                                     Id = GetValue<long>("Id", x),
                                     ProfileImageId = GetValue<Guid?>("ImageId", x),
                                     ContentType = GetValue<string>("ContentType", x),
                                     FirstName = GetValue<string>("Name", x),
                                     LastName = GetValue<string>("LastName", x),
                                     Email = GetValue<string>("Email", x),
                                     PhoenNumber = GetValue<string>("MobilePhoneNumber",x)

                                 }).ToList();

                    sqlDataReader.Close();
                }

                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    if (sqlDataReader != null) sqlDataReader.Close();

                    cmd.Dispose();

                    throw ex;
                }

                finally
                {
                    if (sqlDataReader != null) sqlDataReader.Dispose();

                    cmd.Dispose();
                }

            }


        }

        return customers;
    }
```

I personaly like to use classLibraries for making SQL calls. This might be beyond your question but a personal preference.

As far as entity framework goes my experience is lacking but I think that entity framework + stored proc is a bad idea.

Hope this gives some clarity

Comment: Great answer but it looks like I'm going to have to build models.  In a sense that may not be a bad thing but it is a fair amount of work.  Looking into creating expando classes on the fly but not sure that saves me work.  Thanks for the answer.  If no one else chimes in with better by the end of the day I'll give you credit for the answer.

Comment: Just happy to help:). As an extra note, however you chose to do this it will invole a fair amount of work, if this is the way that saves you work the most maybe not but I belive it is a good way of going about working with stored procedures and MVC

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework will help you with this. I recommend doing code first from database. I don't recommend using MVC and Razor. I would just build a library layer for business logic (this layer will make use of your stored procedures) and Services layer for communication (This layer will only handle communication with client and will use the library to get or set the data). For the client side I would go plain HTML and JavaScript and consume the services with Ajax calls.

If your company has servers that support web sockets I would even go with SignalR hubs instead of WebApi for the service layer.

Comment: ++ for the aggressive approach.  I actually have an API that Is already mostly built out that I can access with ajax calls.  I might go with razor just without the MVC as I might not be able to completely cut the server side cord yet.  SignalR might be fun to play with but would probably be over kill for 90% of what I want to do.  I just need to find a good UI package to support theme-ing.  Might look at that today.  Aguilar if not too much of a pain might be good in the mix too.

Comment: *Angular...spelling isn't my fortay